# How do I set the default_language for Text Search with Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, full-text-search, spring-data-mongodb

In my model I set the `@TextIndexed` annotation to add a field to the fulltext index of MongoDB:

```
@TextIndexed
private String descriptionShort;
```

This works so far.

But how can set the default_language to "De" for the index?

I noticed that the language is automatically set by Spring when a language property is found on the model entity.
At least the behaviour pointed to this conclusion.
However, I did not find any docs on this?

My model has no language property at this point so I wonder how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [unit test's](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/b4487f3dfeddb174076b7c6fbce2c5204498a526/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/TextIndexTests.java#L75-L92) the class can be annotated to the default language through the `@Document` annotation. There is also a section in the [reference documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/1acf00b03928c08b8ebff35625d534390779e9d7/src/main/asciidoc/reference/mapping.adoc#text-indexes). Basically using the same code as in the unit test:

```
@Document(language = "german")
static class TextIndexedDocumentRoot {

        @TextIndexed String textIndexedPropertyWithDefaultWeight;
        @TextIndexed(weight = 5) String textIndexedPropertyWithWeight;

        TextIndexedDocumentWihtLanguageOverride nestedDocument;
    }

    static class TextIndexedDocumentWihtLanguageOverride {

        @Language String lang;

        @TextIndexed String textIndexedPropertyInNestedDocument;

        String nonTextIndexedProperty;
    }
}
```

Just to note that the `@Language` annotation there serves as the [`language_override` setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#use-any-field-to-specify-the-language-for-a-document), but this would actually happen within the "sub-document" as shown with the default field name of `"language"` anyway, and it a common pattern for [enabling multi language support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081485/2313887) with different language phrases stored in the document.

Also note the language can be `"german"` or `"de"` as the ISO code, or anything that is supported on the [Text Search Languages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/) as listed in the documentation. Other options are available in the Enterprise Edition only.